# Meaning of diff_from_typical in ElasticSearch Machine Learning custom rules

Tags: elasticsearch

When configuring Machine Learning jobs in ES, you can customise your detectors by using [custom_rules](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/ml-put-job.html#put-customrules).

I'm wondering about the actual meaning of the `diff_from_typical` (one of the values that `applies_to` can take). My main question is if `diff_from_typical` considers absolute difference or not. I know that you can use `lt` or `gt` operators later (among others) but let's image the following situation:

I have a custom rule for two jobs. The rule is the same but the cases scenarios are different. Let's say that the custom rule is:

```
"custom_rules": [{
        "actions": ["skip_model_update"],
        "conditions": [
          {
            "applies_to": "diff_from_typical",
            "operator": "gt",
            "value": 2000
          }
        ]
      }]
```

Case scenario A:

- Typical value: 5000
- Actual value: 2000
- diff_from_typical: 5000 - 2000 = 3000

Case scenario B:

- Typical value: 5000
- Actual value: 8000
- diff_from_typical: 5000 - 8000 = -3000

Will the aforementioned custom rule apply in both cases? I mean, using the absolute difference from typical? Or will it only work in the first case (case A)?

I assume that if it only works for the first case, I should write the "inverse" custom rule to manage both cases.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question was answered in the ES forum: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/explain-diff-from-typical-meaning-in-custom-rules/304419

Basically, it means absolute difference, so it covers both sides.